# How to subcribe 2 image topics with 1 node in same time?

Tags: ros, kinect, camera, topic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi buddy**,

My name is Toan. I am a newbie in ROS. Now, i'm using Kinect Camera and trying to subcribe 2 image topics with 1 node. But seem like my code is wrong something. If i try to subcribe 1 node with 1 topic is fine. In details, i make case 1 or case 2 is comment , it's work for 1 node 1 topic.

What should i do now ?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import rospy
import numpy as np
import math
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import cv2
#------Start of Class
class image_converter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/kinect/rgb",Image,self.callback_rgb)      #Case 1
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/kinect/depth",Image,self.callback_depth)  #Case 2

    def callback_rgb(self,data):
        cv_image_rgb = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("RGB_Sub", cv_image_rgb)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            rospy.signal_shutdown('Quit')
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
    def callback_depth(self, data):
        cv_image_depth = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("Depth_Sub", cv_image_depth)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            rospy.signal_shutdown('Quit')
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            


def main():
    img_cvt = image_converter()
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
(RGB_Sub:9479): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:179: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312166/how-to-subcribe-2-image-topics-with-1-node-in-same-time-?/) by [ToanJunifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/37567/toanjunifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import message_filters ### ADD THIS
import rospy
import numpy as np
import math
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import cv2

#------Start of Class
class image_converter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        self.depth = message_filters.Subscriber('/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw', Image)
        self.color = message_filters.Subscriber('/camera/color/image_raw', Image)
        
    def callback(self,rgb,depth):
        cv_image_rgb = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb, "bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("RGB_Sub", cv_image_rgb)
        cv_image_depth = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(depth, "bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("Depth_Sub", cv_image_depth)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            rospy.signal_shutdown('Quit')
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    img_cvt = image_converter()
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
    try:
        ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([img_cvt.color,img_cvt.depth],10,0.1)
        ts.registerCallback(img_cvt.callback)
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2020-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2020-11-20**:
Just change the topic and It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although, I'll be honest I don't recognise the error message you're getting I can see a bug in your code.

```
self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/kinect/rgb",Image,self.callback_rgb)      #Case 1
self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/kinect/depth",Image,self.callback_depth)  #Case 2
```

In these two lines you're writing the subscriber objects to the same variable `self.image_sub` so the second one should destroy the first. Try changing the these to two different identifiers, and see if the error continues.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the second one would destroy the first one. But looks like you want to have both the information pieces accessible and process them at the same time. If that's the case, you need to use `TimeSynchronizer` from `message_filters` package. It allows you to have a single callback function for various topics. In your case, it would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import message_filters ### ADD THIS
import rospy
import numpy as np
import math
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import cv2

#------Start of Class
class image_converter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.image_rgb_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/kinect/rgb",Image)      #Case 1
        self.image_depth_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/kinect/depth",Image)  #Case 2

    def callback(self, rgb,depth):
        cv_image_rgb = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(rgb, "bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("RGB_Sub", cv_image_rgb)
        cv_image_depth = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(depth, "bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("Depth_Sub", cv_image_depth)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            rospy.signal_shutdown('Quit')
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    img_cvt = image_converter()
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
    try:
        ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([img_cvt.image_rgb_sub,img_cvt.image_depth_sub],10,0.1)
        ts.registerCallback(callback)
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More info can be found on [this](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy) documentation.

Peace!

---

Originally posted by [robowarrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/38479/robowarrior/) with karma: 46 on 2019-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ToanJunifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/37567/toanjunifer/) on 2019-01-15**:
I got new arror. this:

```
File "/home/junifer/catkin_ws/src/cv_bridge_python/src/Demo_Subcribe_2_topic_and_Display.py", line 33, in main
    ts.registerCallback(callback)
NameError: global name 'callback' is not defined
```

**Comment by [ToanJunifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/37567/toanjunifer/) on 2019-01-15**:
What should i do now ?

**Comment by [sheriarty](https://answers.ros.org/users/109090/sheriarty/) on 2022-06-24**:
did you try

```
ts.registerCallback(img_cvt.callback)
```